# Quarkus application startup bean initalized twice

Tags: quarkus

Following the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#startup_annotation, I created a class to initialize some metadata on startup with the following class:

```java
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppInstance {

    private final UUID id;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppInstance.class);

    AppInstance() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        logger.info("App id: {}", this.id.toString());
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And when I run `mvn quarkus:dev` I see that the message `App id: <some uuid>` is logged twice.

Is this expected behaviour? If so what does this achieve?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe this is expected. The constructor is called twice, once for the actual bean instance, and once for the client proxy (`@ApplicationScoped` beans always get a client proxy). You can make the bean a `@Singleton` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`, and that would get rid of the client proxy and the second constructgor invocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of quarkus do you use? It shouldn't be logged twice in quarkus **1.4.0+** unless the bean is injected somewhere.

The reason why the no-args constructor is called twice is that for normal scoped beans a client proxy is always created using a nor-ags constructor. And this client proxy is a subclass of the `AppInstance`.

In fact, you should not initialize a normal scoped bean like this but use a `@PostConstruct` callback instead.

You can also change the scope of your bean to `javax.inject.Singleton` in which case a client proxy is not used.

Anyway, this is a well-known limitation/feature of CDI normal scopes described in [the spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html) and relevant resources.

Comment: BTW it got fixed in this PR: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/8087

Comment: I was in fact injecting it into another class so i guess that's the reason. I've since switched to using `@Singleton` and everything works fine now.